# Error while using history method in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I tried using the history method to navigate to the home page after the contact is added but i keep getting this error in the console and the form is not navigating

```
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
ERROR in [eslint]
src\App.js
  Line 43:17:  Unexpected use of 'history'  no-restricted-globals
```

This is my code

```
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="appName">
        <Routes>
          <Route  path="/" element={
            <ListContacts
              contacts={this.state.contacts}
              deleteContact={this.removeContact}
            />
          }/>
          <Route path="/create" element={
            <CreateContact 
              onCreateContact = {(contact)=>{
                this.createContact(contact)
                history.push("/")
              }}
            />
          }/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Please use [useNavigate](https://beta.reactrouter.com/en/dev/hooks/use-navigate) to navigate ///

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to the [`history` instance](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history), you have to get a hold of it.

#### The error

You are getting that error because without `useHistory`, the `history` reference actually points to the [global `Window.history` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history). For that reason, you get *"Unexpected use of 'history'  no-restricted-globals"*.

### The fix

If you are using class components, you can get the `history` instance via `this.props.history`. For this, make sure you are using the [`withRouter`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC. After that you could just use:

```
this.props.history.push("/")
```

If you are using function components, you could leverage [`useHistory()`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory):

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";  // <-- added this import

  const history = useHistory();            //  <----- added this line
  return(
      ...
              onCreateContact = {(contact)=>{
                this.createContact(contact)
                history.push("/")
              }}
      ...
```

Comment: But do I have to require useHistory?@acdcjunior

Comment: Actually, since you are using class components, you should probably use `this.props.history.push("/")` and the HOC `withRouter`. I have updated the answer to better explain this.